# MacOS using sysctl() to get HW_MACHINE_ARCH getting "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, macos, kernel, low-level, sysctl

I've been using sysctl for a lot of things recently and now I the HW_MACHINE_ARCH variable. I am using the following code. Note that when I try to get the other variable HW_MACHINE this code works perfectly. I have also thought that maybe the HW_MACHINE_ARCH is a level deeper and put it as a third mib argument but then i got the error "Is a directory". Any ideas as to why this isn't working??

Code:

```
  #import<sys/sysctl.h>

  char *OSArch = (char *)calloc(32, 1);
  mib[0] = CTL_HW;
  mib[1] = HW_MACHINE_ARCH;
  if (sysctl(mib, 2, OSArch, &size_32, NULL, 0) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] OSArch failed. errno: [%d][%s]\n", errno, 
    strerror( errno));
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "OSArch: %s\n", OSArch);
    //fprintf(tdout, "buffer int: %d\n", int_buffer);
  }
  free(OSArch);
```

Comment: what happens if you run sysctl from the command line... something like this `sysctl -a | egrep -i 'hw.machine'`?  I bet it doesn't find anything

Comment: @bruceg Works for me: `hw.machine: x86_64`

Comment: Works well with sysctlbyname, but I have the same problem with your code...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to use `HW_MACHINE` and not `HW_MACHINE_ARCH`

Comment: When I look at sysctl.h I see that both are present. Why is HW_MACHINE_ARCH even there if I can't access it?

Comment: There is some other strange things, for example hw.machine is not part of the output with my sysctl command but in sysctl function call. In fact I found it by using sysctlbyname which gave me the right mib parameters. The fact that the symbols is present doesn't means that the call will give you an answer for it... If you want more info on arch then other symbols are there in mach/machine.h